# Enviar correo por Gmail desde Java

Tags: java

Este módulo envía correo solamente autentificados en Hotmail, como hago para que autentique de igual manera en Gmail y Yahoo?..... Intente agregando la linea: props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");pero no realiza la autentificación por Gmail.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
            //props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            session.setDebug(false);
            BodyPart texto = new MimeBodyPart();
```

Answer (score 4):

Para `Gmail` debes antes modificar el acceso a la cuenta para apps menos seguras, para ello sigue estos pasos:

1. Ir a la [sección de aplicaciones menos seguras](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) en tu cuenta
2. En donde dice `"Acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras"` dale click a `Activar`.

> No está de más recordarte que esto haría que tu cuenta de Gmail sea
>   insegura de ahora en adelante así que usa esto con precaución.

Comment: Hola, haré la prueba a ver si es por configuración de seguridad en la cuenta. gracias! te aviso.

Comment: Así es, modificando la seguridad de la cuenta me funciona sin problemas, lo único es que ahora me funciona para gmail y no para hotmail. creo debo buscar la forma que me acepte ambos servidores. gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @CésarLandaeta me alegra que te haya funcionado. Ahora creo que no se puede poner dos STMP al mismo tiempo y por eso no te funciona en los dos.

Comment: Si, leo algo referente a eso, es muy mal limitar al usuario a usar exclusivamente un dominio específico, pero bueno seguiré leyendo a ver si por allí se encuentra alguna otra solución para esto. gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Pues podrías poner algunas condicionales para los mayores proveedores de email y dejar que el usuario meta algún SMTP custom si fuera necesario. @CésarLandaeta

Comment: ¿Alguien podría explicar el voto negativo si al final esta es la respuesta que resolvió el problema?

Comment: Hola @Gepser si, le realicé las condicionales que comentaste y funciona perfecto, ahora solo estoy tratando de autenticar en Yahoo .. me da error pero ahí continuo. El voto negativo quién lo dio? efectivamente tu respuesta ayudó con la resolución del problema. Gracias

Comment: Hola @CésarLandaeta, si te funcionó la respuesta quizá quieras darle click al botón de "aceptar" la respuesta. Es un ícono en forma de check (✓) que aparece al lado de la respuesta. Esto sirve para que otras personas que se encuentren con tu pregunta sepan qué respuesta es la que solucionó el problema. Saludos

Comment: @CésarLandaeta el voto negativo dí yo, por la razón que la opción de bajar la seguridad de las cuentas de google existe para permitir artefactos antiguos y/o obsoletas de autenticarse en google mail. En este momento la respuesta todavía no incluyó una advertencia sobre la inseguridad del método. Usando las bibliotecas que corresponden se puede perfectamente enviar correos sin comprometer la seguridad de tu cuenta.

Answer (score 4):

Usando [Java mail API 1.4.7](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4.7) el siguiente código funciona. El problema es que Google ahora requiere autenticación de dos pasos.

```
public class Mail {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Mail mail = new Mail("....@gmail.com", "....");
        mail.enviaStartTLS("....@gmail.com", "....@gmail.com", "test", "startTLSTest");

    }

    private String usuario;
    private String pass;

    public Mail(String usuario, String pass){
        this.usuario=usuario;
        this.pass=pass;
    }

    public void enviaStartTLS(String from, String to, String subject, String text){
        final String username = usuario;
        final String password = pass;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Enviado");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


}
```

Como recibo votos negativos para una solución correcta, segura y comprobado sin ninguna indicación porque, ni una pregunta en el casó que no les funcionó, aparentemente tengo que elaborar un poco más:

Si si se refiere al uso de una **API**, eso **implica** de tener una implementación de la api en el **build path**. En el caso concreto eso se refiére a `javaee.jar` y `mail-1.4.7.jar`. Se recomienda de usar el buscador de su confianza para bajar las bibliotecas correctas para la reproducción.

Si uno tiene un problema eléctrico, **¿lo solucionan puenteando el fusible con un clavo?** Yo lo he hecho, pero en casos desesperados, solamente a corto plazo y conociendo los riesgos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Efectivamente lo que me dices es correcto y me funciona con smtp.live.com cuando autentico sin problemas, pero la aplicación debería poder autenticar correos en gmail y yahoo (almenos es lo que se desea). Intente agregar el servidor de gmail pero sigue si autenticarme.

Comment: Con este mismo código de arriba y credenciales correctos?

Comment: En mi aplicación no utilizo la librería Javamail sino que tengo una ventana que me solicita el correo y la contraseña, es decir que en el código no coloco la dirección/contraseña, sino que es solicitada y autenticada al comienzo del programa. Con esto lo que se quiere es no limitar al usuario a usar exclusivamente una cuenta gmail, hotmail o yahoo cualquiera sea el caso. El pedazo de código que viste es solo la parte donde describo los servidores y como había comentado con smtp.live.com autentica sin problemas, pero cuando agrego la linea smtp.gmail.com o smtp.mail.yahoo.com no funciona.

Comment: Con este código no necesitas bajar la seguridad de tu cuenta en google.

Comment: @CésarLandaeta JavaMail API es la principal forma de enviar correos en Java. Si no lo usas, imagino que usarás otra librería para enviar el correo. Sería conveniente [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código con el que también ejecutas el envío del correo.